# how to de-serialize JSON data in which Timestamp it-self contains fields?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am Unable to map the class with the given JSON data:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (15min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-09-28 15:45:00",
        "4. Interval": "15min",
        "5. Output Size": "Full size",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (15min)": {
        "2018-09-28 15:45:00": {
            "1. open": "114.2800",
            "2. high": "114.5600",
            "3. low": "114.2400",
            "4. close": "114.4800",
            "5. volume": "2316251"
        },
        "2018-09-28 15:30:00": {
            "1. open": "114.4450",
            "2. high": "114.4500",
            "3. low": "114.2600",
            "4. close": "114.2900",
            "5. volume": "759991"
        },
        "2018-09-28 15:15:00": {
            "1. open": "114.3550",
            "2. high": "114.5200",
            "3. low": "114.3100",
            "4. close": "114.4400",
            "5. volume": "515174"
        }
    }
}
```

How to create class structure structure so that i can de-serialize the above data using newtonsoft in c#?

Comment: What about a dictionary, assuming you can't have any duplicates?

Comment: Do i need to consider timestamp(2018-09-28 15:45:00) itself a class name? i think it is not good to create class by timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Using the help of [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) and a bit of editing, I created these classes:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Time Series (15min)")]
    public Dictionary<DateTime, TimeSeriesItem> TimeSeries15Min { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string The1Information { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
    public string The2Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
    public DateTimeOffset The3LastRefreshed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. Interval")]
    public string The4Interval { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. Output Size")]
    public string The5OutputSize { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("6. Time Zone")]
    public string The6TimeZone { get; set; }
}

public class TimeSeriesItem
{
    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public string The1Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public string The2High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public string The3Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public string The4Close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
    public long The5Volume { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize it like so:

```
var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/VWB53959)

Comment: Thanks a lot .. ya it is working fine.  :) it is really helpful for me as i have just started working on JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution, test included... I generally use [this Json Class Jenerator](http://www.xamasoft.com/json-class-generator/) for generating the classes, on occasion you do need to modify the classes it outputs but generally speaking, it's pretty good

```
void Main()
{
    string test = @"{
    ""Meta Data"": {
        ""1. Information"": ""Intraday (15min) open, high, low, close prices and volume"",
        ""2. Symbol"": ""MSFT"",
        ""3. Last Refreshed"": ""2018-09-28 15:45:00"",
        ""4. Interval"": ""15min"",
        ""5. Output Size"": ""Full size"",
        ""6. Time Zone"": ""US/Eastern""
    },
    ""Time Series (15min)"": {
        ""2018-09-28 15:45:00"": {
            ""1. open"": ""114.2800"",
            ""2. high"": ""114.5600"",
            ""3. low"": ""114.2400"",
            ""4. close"": ""114.4800"",
            ""5. volume"": ""2316251""
        },
        ""2018-09-28 15:30:00"": {
            ""1. open"": ""114.4450"",
            ""2. high"": ""114.4500"",
            ""3. low"": ""114.2600"",
            ""4. close"": ""114.2900"",
            ""5. volume"": ""759991""
        },
        ""2018-09-28 15:15:00"": {
            ""1. open"": ""114.3550"",
            ""2. high"": ""114.5200"",
            ""3. low"": ""114.3100"",
            ""4. close"": ""114.4400"",
            ""5. volume"": ""515174""
        }
    }
}";

    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(test).Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class MetaData
{
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string Information { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. Symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")]
    public string LastRefreshed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. Interval")]
    public string Interval { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. Output Size")]
    public string OutputSize { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("6. Time Zone")]
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
}

public class CandleStick
{

    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public string Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public string High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public string Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public string Close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }
}


public class Result
{

    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Time Series (15min)")]
    public Dictionary<DateTime, CandleStick> TimeSeries15min { get; set; }
}
```

[image]