# Get all values from JObject and save it into list c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have below json string i have converted into JObject.

I want to get the values from that JObject and insert into List so that I can insert that data into SQL later use.

json data -

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
    },
    "Time Series (5min)": {
        "2020-03-26 16:00:00": {
            "1. open": "156.2200",
            "2. high": "156.7400",
            "3. low": "154.6100",
            "4. close": "155.9500",
            "5. volume": "4185884"
        },
        "2020-03-26 15:55:00": {
            "1. open": "152.5700",
            "2. high": "156.2500",
            "3. low": "152.5700",
            "4. close": "156.2400",
            "5. volume": "2648305"
        }
    }
}
```

c# Code -

```
    HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    var result = _client.GetAsync("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo").Result;
    var data = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    JObject json = JObject.Parse(data);

    var timeSeries = JObject.Parse(data)["Time Series (5min)"];
```

I want to take out all values like below so that in SQL table i can insert it like -

```
Date                | Position   | Value

2020-03-26 16:00:00 |  1. open   | 156.2200
2020-03-26 16:00:00 |  2. high   | 156.7400
2020-03-26 16:00:00 |  3. low    | 154.6100
2020-03-26 16:00:00 |  4. close  | 155.9500
2020-03-26 16:00:00 |  5. volume | 4185884
2020-03-26 15:55:00 |  1. open   | 152.5700
2020-03-26 15:55:00 |  2. high   | 156.2500
2020-03-26 15:55:00 |  3. low    | 152.5700
2020-03-26 15:55:00 |  4. close  | 156.2400
2020-03-26 15:55:00 |  5. volume | 2648305
```

I dont find `[]` in giving json output so not sure how to traverse and get data.

Comment: I am not familiar with JObject. However, that JObject, should have a property called TimeSeries(5min) or something to that effect, look through the returned object in your IDE or just look at the object itself, for the property, step through that array with a foreach loop, for loop or while loop, and then pr line, insert the data you want via an ORM, like entityframework. Should be relatively straight forward. 

But you should likely split this question up into sections, how to traverse a list, how to make an insert in a database, and so fourth.

Comment: You can also consider creating classes and deserializing your son content into these classes to have type safety and strongly typed programming experience.

Comment: Here is another approach which might be easier to work with: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52577013/10263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By getting the properties and casting them to JObject as required, you can have the result you want:

```
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(data);

        foreach (JProperty dateTime in json["Time Series (5min)"])
        {
            foreach (JProperty property in (dateTime.Value as JObject).Properties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-24}{1,-16}{2,-16}", dateTime.Name, property.Name, property.Value);
            }
        }
```

Here is the output:

```
2020-03-26 16:00:00     1. open         156.2200
2020-03-26 16:00:00     2. high         156.7400
2020-03-26 16:00:00     3. low          154.6100
2020-03-26 16:00:00     4. close        155.9500
2020-03-26 16:00:00     5. volume       4185884
2020-03-26 15:55:00     1. open         152.5700
2020-03-26 15:55:00     2. high         156.2500
2020-03-26 15:55:00     3. low          152.5700
2020-03-26 15:55:00     4. close        156.2400
2020-03-26 15:55:00     5. volume       2648305
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a `Time Series (5min)` token using indexer `[]`, because it isn't an array. Try to cast it to `JObject` an enumerate its [`Properties()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Properties.htm) to get an expected result, which can be easily parsed into list of tuples or other type

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(data);

var timeSeries = new List<Item>();
var series = (JObject)json["Time Series (5min)"];
foreach (var serie in series.Properties())
{
    var items = (JObject)serie.Value;
    timeSeries.AddRange(items.Properties()
        .Select(item => new Item
        {
            Date = serie.Name, Position = item.Name, Value = item.Value.Value<double>()
        }));
}
```

`Item` class for the reference

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit more concise LINQ expression for your consideration:

```cs
var timeSeries = JObject.Parse(data)["Time Series (5min)"].Cast<JProperty>();
var result = timeSeries.SelectMany(ts => (ts.Value as JObject).Properties(), (obj, props) => new {Date = obj.Name, Position = props.Name, props.Value });
```

Pretty much the same nested iteration over `JProperties` all the way down to Value level

Comment: You should store the `SelectMany` result in a variable